# Error component: inertia-link con Laravel Jetstream Inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertia.js

estoy desarrollando una admin para tener todo la información de mis clientes y tengo un problema con  .

Puedo ver la pantalla sin problemas, pero el botón botón no funciona.
Este es el código del botón:

```
<inertia-link
 :href="route('clientes.create')"
 class=" type="button">
   Nuevo Cliente
</inertia-link>
```

El scrip que tengo al final es:

```
import JetApplicationLogo from '@/Jetstream/ApplicationLogo.vue'
    import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout'
    import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

    export default {
        props:{
        productos: Array
       },
        components: {
            JetApplicationLogo,
            Link,
        },
    };
```

En la consola sale esto:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: inertia-link 
  at <ClienteMostrar> 
  at <AppLayout title="Clientes" > 
  at <Clientes jetstream= 
Object { canCreateTeams: false, canManageTwoFactorAuthentication: true, canUpdatePassword: true, canUpdateProfileInformation: true, flash: [], hasAccountDeletionFeatures: true, hasApiFeatures: false, hasTeamFeatures: false, hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature: false, managesProfilePhotos: true }
 user= 
Object { id: 1, name: "Oscar", email: "mail@mail.com", email_verified_at: "fecha", current_team_id: null, profile_photo_path: null, created_at: "fecha", updated_at: "fecha", profile_photo_url: "https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=Oscar&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF", two_factor_enabled: false }
 errorBags= 
Array []
  ... > 
  at <Inertia initialPage= 
Object { component: "Clientes", props: {…}, url: "/clientes", version: "207fd484b7c2ceeff7800b8c8a11b3b6" }
 initialComponent= 
Object { components: {…}, render: render(_ctx, _cache, $props, $setup, $data, $options)
, __file: "resources/js/Pages/Clientes.vue", inheritAttrs: false, … }
 resolveComponent=fn<m>  ... > 
  at <App>
```

Gracias por su ayuda :)

Comment: No conozco inertia, pero posiblemente porque en components usas `Link`, y el template `inertia-link`. Que pasa si en el template usas `<Link :href="..." type="button">Nuevo Cliente</Link>`. Además parece que tienes una comilla sin cerrar en el atributo class

Comment: Hola, gracias. La comilla puede que se me escapará cuando saqué toda la clase, para que no quedará tanta largo.
Probe con <Link> pero no fucniona.

Comment: Y te dá el mismo error?

Comment: En consola no da error, pero tampoco hace nada el botón. Hago click y nada

Answer (score 0):

Te olvidas de poner AppLayout en los componentes a exportar, tal vez sea eso, tenía el mismo problema, pero yo lo solucioné cambiando todos los inertia-link por Link solamente y poniendo:

> import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3

y en export default

> components:{
> AppLayout,
> Link
> }